# Linux Manjaro - Linkage Error and AVD/SDK/Emulator not found error. (Android Emulator setup for VSCode)

Tags: android, linux, visual-studio-code, emulation, manjaro

Ive been trying to setup my android emulator via VSCode on my Linux Manjaro machine.
Though I get the error:
AVD Manager Not found/Not exist!
and
SDK Manager Not found/Not exist!
Etc...
When running the sdkmanager --version command:
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/lib/libnio.so: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/lib/libnio.so: undefined symbol: reuseport_available

I have tried different jave version. 8 to 21.
I have tried reinstalling the cmd-tools from android multiple times and manually setting the paths for these such that VSCode could use it without luck.